# Theano CUDA exception

Tags: python, theano, mnist

I'm relatively new to theano and I want to run the mnist example on my
GPU but I get the following output:

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 970M (CNMeM is disabled)
Loading data...
Building model and compiling functions...
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock):
    Overriding existing lock by dead process '9700' (I am process '10632')

DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT mod.cu
Creating library 
  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Theano
    /compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_71_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-64
    /tmp55nlvvvo/m25b839e7715203be227800f03e7c8fe8.lib 
and object 
  C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Theano
    /compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_71_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-64
    /tmp55nlvvvo/m25b839e7715203be227800f03e7c8fe8.exp
```

It keeps outputting DEBUG messages without any output of mnist.
I have a working version of nvcc:

```
C:\Users\user>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:49:10_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

And my `.theanorc` file:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am also having this problem, though not with that example program. Anaconda python 3.4, GeForce GTX970, Windows 10, theano 0.8rc1. Looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. Search google and get the code. https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/nvcc_compiler.py

```
        p = subprocess.Popen(
                cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        nvcc_stdout_raw, nvcc_stderr_raw = p.communicate()[:2]
        console_encoding = getpreferredencoding()
        nvcc_stdout = decode_with(nvcc_stdout_raw, console_encoding)
        nvcc_stderr = decode_with(nvcc_stderr_raw, console_encoding)

    if nvcc_stdout:
        # this doesn't happen to my knowledge
        print("DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT", nvcc_stdout, file=sys.stderr)
```

It seems to nvcc have error output.

But in my occasion, its output looks like

> DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT mod.cu
>
> DEBUG: nvcc STDOUT mod.cu

Sometimes the program work fine after this, sometimes doesn't work. It's very strange.
Sorry I can not make comment, so I just post the answer.

Comment: I just find that if I disable the integrated graphics, everything goes fine. If you have two graphics, you can try this.